# How to disable terraform error "Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again." for data block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

Can someone tell me how to disable the raising of the error if the terraform data block result is empty? I want to handle this situation myself.
My code is below.

```
data "aws_ami" "specified" {
    for_each = toset([
        for v in var.ec2_confg_params : v.ami if v.ami != null
    ])
    most_recent        = true
    include_deprecated = false

    filter {
        /*
          Filter based on the '--filters (list)' keys described here
          https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html
        */
        name = "image-id"
        values = [
        each.value,
       ]
    }

    filter {
        name   = "state"
        values = ["available"]
    }

    lifecycle {
        postcondition {
        condition = try(each.value == self.id)
        error_message = "Image '${each.value}' not found!"
        }
    }
}
```

If the value `var.ec2_confg_params.ami` is set but the date block does not find it, I get an error:

> Error: Your query returned no results. Please change your search criteria and try again.
> │
> │   with data.aws_ami.specified["ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"],
> │   on main.tf line 293, in data "aws_ami" "specified":
> │  293: data "aws_ami" "specified" {

but I need the `lifecycle postcondition` block to work.
Thanks in advance for help!

The only solution I found is to select all AMIs with `data.aws_ami_ids`, and check if the ami in `var.ec2_confg_params.ami` is in the list `data.aws_ami_ids.all.ids`. But this option is processed for a long time and it is difficult to set parameters for filtering based on AMI 'owner'.

Comment: This is not possible. Data sources are used to query about resources that already exist. So it's not on the data source to do nothing rather you should make sure you know what you are filtering and if the image exists. Otherwise you may as well hard code the AMI ID.

Answer (score 0):

This particular data source is designed to return exactly one AMI matching the given criteria or return an error if that isn't possible. There is no way to change that behavior.

It is in principle possible for a provider to offer a data resource that *doesn't* fail when an object doesn't exist, or to return a set of objects that all together match some criteria. The `hashicorp/aws` provider offers [`aws_ami_ids`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ami_ids) as an alternative which returns a set of IDs matching the given criteria, and so you could potentially get the result you wanted using that data source instead:

```
data "aws_ami_ids" "example" {
  for_each = toset([
    for v in var.ec2_confg_params : v.ami
    if v.ami != null
  ])

  filter {
    name = "image-id"
    values = [
      each.value,
    ]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  lifecycle {
    postcondition {
      condition     = length(self.ids) == 1
      error_message =  "Image '${each.value}' not found."
    }
  }
}
```

This is an unusual approach though, since it's just replacing an error case that the provider already handles with exactly the same error case implemented in your module. Unless you have a particular reason to return a different error message than normal I would suggest using the built-in behavior for simplicity.

Comment: Hi [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins)! Thanks for your reply. But, your example won't work. Data block 'aws_ami_ids' need option 'owners'. As I wrote in my question: "The only solution I found is to select all AMIs with data.aws_ami_ids, and check if the ami in var.ec2_confg_params.ami is in the list data.aws_ami_ids.all.ids. But this option is processed for a long time and it is difficult to set parameters for filtering based on AMI 'owner'." But this option does not suit me because of the long time to fetch the data.

Comment: Now I have made this validation optional until I find a more convenient solution. Anyway thanks for your answer [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848/martin-atkins).